# Launchd schedule for last day of month

Tags: launchd

I'm trying to schedule a job for the last day of every month using Launchd but I'm not quite sure how to do it.  It seems the only options I get are numerals for selecting the day of the month so, for example, I can select to run on day 31, but what happens in February and September?  If the value is 31, does Launchd just run it on the highest number day for each month?

Thanks for any help!

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a "nice" way of expressing the last day of each month. If you do "31" it simply won't run in February or months ending in 30.

Can you work around that requirement, and simply use midnight of the first day of each month?

You *could* be verbose and do the following in the plist, and define the last day of each month. It will break in a leap year when February has 29 days.

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>31</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>28</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </dict>     
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>31</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I'll take your first suggestion, though.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah — the first second of the the first day of the month, for the vast majority of purposes, ought to be good enough :-) Good luck.